# Using forms API - sending submitted data as an XML attachment to an email address

Tags: forms

I need to have a request form on a D7 site which does a few different things with the form data:

- Writes to database table (standard);
- Emails a copy of the form data to a site administrator on a pre-defined email address;
- Creates a XML file attachment in a prescribed format (not valid XML, so possibly best being a template with placeholder values being replaced by form data) which is also attached to the email to administrator.

The generation of the XML is currently working fine in a bespoke PHP system and I'm thinking for ease re-using the functionality would make good sense.

However, is there a simple way to hook this into the submit process for the Drupal form? I believe using the Forms API may be the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement the [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) and add your custom submit handler.

See this article for an intro into hooking into forms:
http://websmiths.co/blog/very-introduction-drupals-hookformalter